# How to share DbContext between multiple threads

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, task-parallel-library, entity-framework-plus

I'm trying to implement a bulk insert and delete operation based on some specifications i.e `IList<Specification>` provided by the user. The data which needs to be queried is roundabout 1 million, based on which I need to insert or delete records to/from another table i.e `UserSpecifications` table which have only two columns `UserId` and `SpecificationId` and PK is `UserId + SpecificationId`

Order in which the records get inserted/deleted into `UserSpecifications` table doesn't matter

Hence I'm trying to create Parallel tasks for each user specification and process data into  `UserSpecifications`

```
    await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(specifications, async specification =>
    {
        await insertBulkRecordsAsync(specification); // this uses SqlBulkCopy for data insertion with transaction scope , on 1 million records
        await deleteRecordsAsync(specification); // this uses https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-delete operation
    }));
```

both `insertBulkRecordsAsync` & `deleteRecordsAsync` uses userContext

When I try to run this piece of code I get the following exception

```
The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.
```

I know that EF 6 doesn't support sharing dbContext, but if I run a normal forEach loop things do work but it takes a lot of time to process the  updates

Following works without any issue

```
foreach (var specification in specifications)
{
  await insertBulkRecordsAsync(specification);
  await deleteRecordsAsync(specification);
}
```

So do we have any way to share the context and increase the execution time

Comment: 1) do not use EF for bulk operations (or at least search for extensions to handle them) 2) if you still need to do this via EF - create context per thread.

Comment: I don't understand: if you are already using `SqlBulkCopy` what is the `foreach` for?

Comment: @Charlieface the forEach is on user input as inside `insertBulkRecordsAsync` have some custom extension methods which further drill-downs the select statement, something like 
`var dataToUpdate = this.userContext.users.where(u => u.age >12)
.CustomExtensionMethod(specification)
.ToDataTable()` and then `sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataToUpdate)`

Comment: So perhaps you can merge them all into one giant bulk-insert

Comment: @GuruStron for the 1st point we have some set of extension methods that take the specification inserted by the user and run it against the users' list `this.userContext.users.where(u => u.age >12) .CustomExtensionMethod(specification) `
2nd point I didn't understand, I'm injecting my context through autofac

Comment: @Charlieface `CustomExtensionMethod` adds set of `IQueryable` based on the specification that is passed and attach it to `this.userContext.users.where` hence iterations are unavoidable, let say I iterate and store the values into a huge datatable and push everything in a giant bulk-insert I'm still at the same point as I have to do this synchronously and wait for one loop to complete

Comment: @AkhilRJ you should probably edit the question and explain the *actual* problem without any mention of EF Core. It's not relevant - it's simply *not* meant to be used across threads or for bulk operations. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection to be shared among threads.

Comment: @AkhilRJ If you want to insert lots of data to SQL Server use SqlBulkCopy. You can pass a DataReader to it, not just a DataTable. If your data comes from another database, you can use ExecuteDataReader and pass the generated reader to WriteToServerAsync. If the data is a list in memory, you can use FastMember's ObjectReader to put a DataReader interface over the list, and pass it to SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: @AkhilRJ there's no such thing as bulk update or delete. If you want to delete or update lots of rows you need to either write a query that modifies all records at once, or *batch* multiple operations together. EF Core gets in the way here. You can use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to make writing the UPDATE queries as easy as a single line.